# Where is ConnectPoints plugin on QGIS 3, or what is alternative?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, qgis-3

I need ConnectPoints plugin in QGIS, to do as same as on this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aZTpZ_NzwN8 
But I cant it find it in QGIS 3.0. Is there any alternative plugin which can do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In QGIS 3.0 you can use the built-in "Join by lines" algorithm. This performs the exact same task as "ConnectPoints", but is a Processing algorithm so has extra benefits, e.g. it can be used in models and in batch processing modes.